# How to git merge theirs *without* automerging?

Tags: git

I have a `master` and `develop` branch that I always want to accept what's in `develop` as the source of truth, overwriting any changes in master.

How can I do this? I though this would do it

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b merge_to_master
$ git merge develop --strategy-option theirs
```

but sometimes, it automerges files incorrectly, without conflict. This may be due to some developers committing some things to master, but even if that's the case, I want to ignore this, and overwrite their change, and keep all the commits we had in `develop`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beware of the fact that `git merge develop -Xtheirs` (similar to your `git merge develop --strategy-option theirs`) is NOT a way to "accept what's in develop as the source of truth, overwriting any changes in master"

It will take "theirs" (in your case, `master`) version for every **conflicting chunk**, but any other (non-conflicting) change will be treated in the usual way, taking everything from both parents when able to.

To merge while taking *everything* from one parent, making the result exactly similar in terms of code as one parent, you have another option, which is to use `-s ours` on the side you want to keep (since unfortunately the "theirs" counterpart doesn't exist).

It could go like this

```
git checkout -b develop-copy develop
git merge -s ours master
git checkout master
git merge develop-copy
```

At this point, `master` has the exact same tree `develop` has, and the branches are considered merged for all further purposes.